# chown -R not working in Yocto-Project recipe

Tags: yocto, openembedded

Sorry, I'm not a native English speaker.

I'm trying to install my web application using a Yocto-Project recipe file.

```
PR = "r0"
PV = "1.0"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING;md5=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"

SRC_URI = "\
    file://sources \
    file://COPYING \
"
S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${localstatedir}/www
    cp -r ${S}/sources/* ${D}${localstatedir}/www/
    chown -R www-data:www-data ${D}${localstatedir}/www/
    chmod -R 775 ${D}${localstatedir}/www/cgi-bin
}
```

But `/var/www` is still owned by `root:root` and not `www-data:www-data` like desired.

## Question

So how do I `chown` the `/var/www` directory recusively to `www-data:www-data`?

## EDIT

I have seen page 9 of the following presentation: https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/images/e/e6/Custom_Users_Groups_in_Yocto1.1.pdf .

I created this recipe file to mimic this page.

Comment: Are you running this script as root?  Is www-data a valid user / group?  Did you get any error messages from `chown`?  How are variables `D` and `localstatedir`  set?  Without these details, nobody can make the guess work for you.

Comment: No, running this script as default user not root.Yes, www-data is valid user / group.

Comment: You can't `chown` a file/directory not owned by you unless you are root.

Comment: if cannot `chown`, then error may be occurred.I think this problem is concerned in `pseudo`. `pseudo` is used building yocto recipes, and it can  become a user which is pseudo-root.

Comment: create a cron job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `chown` and `chmod` should work in YP/OE recipes the way you use them.

The problem may be that you've missed a `/` in your path arguments for the commands. According to the documentation [1] `${D}` has no trailing `/`.

Therefore the following should work:

```
do_install() {
  install -d ${D}/${localstatedir}/www
  cp -r ${S}/sources/* ${D}/${localstatedir}/www/
  chown -R www-data:www-data ${D}/${localstatedir}/www/
  chmod -R 775 ${D}/${localstatedir}/www/cgi-bin
}
```

(If not please post your bitbake logs)

[1] https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-D

Comment: `${localstatedir}` starts with a slash. I.e. `/var`.

Answer (score -2):

sudo chown -R wwwdata:wwwdata  /var/www/ to make the ownership of the desired folder and its inner folders or files recursively

Comment: Nope, this may work on a normal shell, but this question is about a YP/OE recipe.